# Is there a way to access Mac system fonts in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, mac

I am mocking up a Mac App interface on El Capitan and would like to use the San Francisco system font. However the San Francisco font doesn't appear in Photoshop's font menu. Is there a way to access the system fonts in Photoshop?

Comment: This is just a guess, have you looked for the font in /System/Library/Fonts/? You might have to put the font in ~/Library/Fonts/.

Comment: If a font is installed correctly, it ought to show up in all software - Photoshop is not an exception. Check if you can see it with FontBook.

Comment: @Jongware I [can't see it](http://i.imgur.com/oLmGxAe.png) in Font Book. I assumed that's because Apple hides system fonts intentionally.  All the other Font Book fonts are in Photoshop ok.

Comment: Looks like this is a common issue people are having. See this thread on the Adobe forums: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1852440

Comment: @Jongware: this is actually not true, and has been a problem for a long time. In windows, there is a fonts folder under, i think, ( programfiles/common/adobe/ } and the quick fix is to create a *shortcut* to the system fonts folder in that special adobe folder. All the properly installed fonts that fail to show up in the font list(s) will then show up. It works adobe-wide. The shortcut is preferred so you don't have to double-install fonts. This works on mac too AFAIK, but the locations are different. There have been posts on this site about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that Apple has intentionally locked down the default system font.

However you can [download a development version](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) of the font which you can install **in addition** to the system version. It has tight licensing restrictions, mockups only, but that's all I needed it for, so this solution worked well for me.

[image]

More detail can be found on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208854/49826).